# Why I don't need Content-type when my DirectoryIndex points to a Perl CGI script

Tags: html, perl, apache2, cgi, directoryindex

I changed the file mods-available/dir.conf this way:

```
DirectoryIndex /cgi-bin/csv_auth
```

In `csv_auth` which is a Perl CGI script I have this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

package Logger;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use POSIX qw( strftime );

sub debug {
  my $msg = shift;

  mkdir '/tmp/authorize';
  my $fn = '/tmp/authorize/auth.txt';
  open (my $fh, '>>', $fn) or die "Could not open file $fn: $!";
  my $timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime);
  say $fh "$timestamp : $msg";
}

package CGI::Session::Auth::CSV;                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use parent 'CGI::Session::Auth';                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
use Text::CSV;

# Need to override new()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my ($params) = shift;
  Logger::debug('CGI::Session::Auth::CSV::new() called');
  $class = ref($class) if ref($class);
  # initialize parent class                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  my $self = $class->SUPER::new($params);
  bless($self, $class);
  return $self;
}

# Override the _login method to use a CSV file                                                                                                                                                                                                    
sub _login {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($user, $pass) = @_;
  $self->{username} = $user;
  Logger::debug('CGI::Session::Auth::CSV::_login() called');
  my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
  open my $fh, '<', 'login.csv' or die "Can't open login.csv: $!";
  # Loop through the rows and check for a match                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    Logger::debug("CGI::Session::Auth::CSV::_login() : user and psswrd : $user $pass");
    Logger::debug("CGI::Session::Auth::CSV::_login() : CSV row 0 and 1 : $row->[0] $row->[1]");
    if ($row->[0] eq $user and $row->[1] eq $pass) {
      # Found a match, return true                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      close $fh;
      Logger::debug("CGI::Session::Auth::CSV::_login() : found match for username: $user");
      #return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }
  }
  # No match, return false                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  close $fh;
  #return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}

package main;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use feature qw(say);                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
use CGI(-utf8);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
use CGI::Cookie;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
use CGI::Session;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
use utf8;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
use File::Copy;

# CGI object for headers, cookies, etc.                                                                                                                                                                                                           
my $cgi = CGI->new();

my $user = $cgi->param('log_username');
my $password = $cgi->param('log_password');
my $cmd = $cgi->param('cmd');

my %cgi_vars = $cgi->Vars;
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : query parameters: ' . Dumper(\%cgi_vars));
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : cookies: ' . (join ',', $cgi->cookie()));
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : cookie: CGISESSID : ' . Dumper($cgi->cookie('CGISESSID')));

# CGI::Session object for session handling                                                                                                                                                                                                        
my $session = CGI::Session->new(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp/authorize'});
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : session = ' . $session->dump());
my $session_params = $session->dataref();
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : session data : ' . Dumper($session_params));
my $session_params_text = Dumper($session_params);
if (defined $user) {
  $session->param('username', $user);
  $session->flush();
} else {
  $user = $session->param('username');
}
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name   => $session->name,
                           -value  => $session->id );
print $cgi->header( -cookie=>$cookie );
# CGI::Session::Auth object for authentication                                                                                                                                                                                                    
my $auth = CGI::Session::Auth::CSV->new({CGI => $cgi, Session => $session});
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : auth object 1 : ' . Dumper($auth));
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : calling authenticate');
$auth->authenticate();
Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : auth object 2 : ' . Dumper($auth));
if ($cmd eq 'logout') {
  logout($auth, $user);
  exit;
}

# check if visitor has already logged in                                                                                                                                                                                                          
if ($auth->loggedIn) {
  Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : user is logged in');
  print <<HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<h3>Hello you are lógged in $user</h3>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<p><a href='rp.cgi?cmd=logout'>Log out</a></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
} else {
  Logger::debug('cgiscript: rp.cgi : user is not logged in');
  show_login_page();
}
$session->flush();

sub show_login_page {
  my $self = shift;
  print <<HTML;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<head><title>Not logged in</title></head>                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<h1>You are not logged in</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<p>Please log in to see the secret page:</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<form action='/cgi-bin/rp.cgi' method='POST'>
<p><input type='text' size='30'' name='log_username'</p>                                                                                                                                                                                          
<p><input type='password' size='30' name='log_password'</p>                                                                                                                                                                                       
<p><input type='submit'></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</form>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}

sub logout {
  my ($auth, $user) = @_;
  auth->logout();
  print <<HTML;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<head><title>Logged out</title></head>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<h1>You have logged out user $user.</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<p>Please log in to see the secret page:</p>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<form action='maing.cgi' method='POST'>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
<p><input type='text' size='30' name='log_username'></p>                                                                                                                                                                                          
<p><input type='email' size='30' name='log_password'></p>                                                                                                                                                                                         
<p><input type='submit'></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</form>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
</html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
HTML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

And then my browser shows this if I `print Content-type`:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Hello you are logged in marcos
```

This is the header for response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Aug 2023 05:02:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
Set-Cookie: CGISESSID=fc23b50f1b15cbf978e5f797fddc9986; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 240
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

This is the request header:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: recordspreservation.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: CGISESSID=fc23b50f1b15cbf978e5f797fddc9986
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-GPC: 1
```

It should not show `Content-type` but it does. Does that mean that when my initial page is a Perl CGI then I don't need the `Content-type` line?

Thanks!

Comment: Re "*Does that mean that when my initial page is a Perl CGI then I don't need the Content-type line?*", No, it means you are printing two headers.

Comment: Show the entire HTTP response including headers. Use the CLI `curl` to make that task simple.

Comment: @John Hanley I update the question with the headers.

Comment: @ikegami How do I prevent the second header coming from the cgi script from being printed?

Comment: I need to see the `\n` characters. Two are used to separate the headers from the body. Include everything, not just what you think is important. My guess is that you are trying to send two sets of headers - which will not work.

Comment: Re "*How do I prevent the second header coming from the cgi script from being printed?*" You send (print) two headers. Only send one. If you want specifics, you'll need to provide a demonstration of the problem (as required).

Comment: ikegami Is it as simple as removing `print Content-type` from perl script?

Comment: I updated the header information again.

Comment: You need to tag someone (`@ikegami`) for them to get notified if it's not their post

Comment: Re "*my browser shows this if I `print Content-type:`*", Sound like you're saying you didn't post the code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Note that the code you posted already prints a header (`print $cgi->header( -cookie=>$cookie );`). Of course you'll have problems if you print a second. Don't do that.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! Besides printer the header, what does the -cookie=>cookie do? Does it store the cookie in the browser?

Comment: Set the Set-Cookie header, which the goal of setting a cookie in the browser.

Comment: @ikegami Let's suppose a cookie already exists in the browser for my website. Then another cookie is not set, correct? With print $header(-cookie)``, does the browser immediately sends the cookie ID number back to the server which in turn checks to see if the file cgisess_* that matches the cookie ID exists in /tmp? Is there a flowchat of what CGI::Session does?

Comment: If there's already a cookie with the same name, it will be replaced.

Comment: @ikegami Replaced with a cookie with the same ID or with a different ID?

Comment: Replace a cookie with the same name, I said. Cookies have a name, a value, info about the urls to which to provide it, and an expiry date-time.